# iOS app fails after SSL certificate upgradation on server

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, ssl-certificate

We have an iOS app that reads information from our secure web server through RestApi. Everything was working great until SSL certificates were installed on the server. After installation, all api calls were changed from HTTP to HTTPS. Interesting thing is that, the app runs well when we access internet from one of the ISP’s that we have and on the other it fails.

Can anyone give us some suggestions to solve the issue that we have now.

Comment: Are you using a self signed certificate?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the request and trapping the error message and response status code.  The error message should tell you exactly what the problem is.